# how to generate pie chart using dict_values in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, counter, pie-chart

I wanted the frequency of numbers in a list which I got using `Counter` library. Also, I got the keys and values using `keys = Counter(list).keys()` and `values = Counter(list).values()` respectively, where `list` is the list of numbers. Their output are in following form:

```
dict_keys(['0.2200', '0.2700', '0.6200', '0.3000', '0.2500', '0.3400', '0.5600', '0.3900', '0.5400', '0.5500', '0.7500', '0.4100', '0.2800', '0.4200', '0.3800', '0.6600', '0.2000', '0.5200', '0.7200'])
```

and,
    dict_values([15, 3, 6, 13, 6, 3, 1, 3, 3, 5, 4, 14, 8, 5, 3, 5, 11, 3, 9])

Now I want to generate a pie-chart using keys and values which i did it in following way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
pyplot.axis("equal")
pyplot.pie(float(values),labels=float(keys),autopct=None)
pyplot.show()
```

But, I get the error as:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'
```

Is there any way to convert `dict_values` to string or number as the function used to generate pie chart only accepts string or number?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to loop through the values and convert them *individually* to floats:

```
pyplot.pie([float(v) for v in values], labels=[float(k) for k in keys],
           autopct=None)
```

The `[expression for target in iterable]` is called a list comprehension and produces a list object.

I'd not create the `Counter()` twice; create it just once and reuse:

```
counts = Counter(yourlist)
pyplot.pie([float(v) for v in counts.values()], labels=[float(k) for k in counts],
           autopct=None)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution generates the pie exactly the way i needed. I will keep in mind that i have to convert the values individually from now on. thanks again :)